# Handling back button using sliding Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using sliding menu which has four menu items, I will load different fragment's on each click of menu. Here is my problem when user click on first menu item and then some other menu item , If he clicks on the back button, First menu should be selected. with fragment which need to store in stack. How can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to implement adding Fragments to back stack, right? If so you just have to add

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(<string_tag_or_null>);
```

to the code invoking FragmentTransaction.